# VS For Mac And ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, xamarin, asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac

Now that there is Visual Studio for Mac, is it possible to do everything you do on Windows also on Mac? I've read that I should be using ASP.NET Core instead of the full ASP.NET framework if I want to use a Mac. What kind of restrictions does this cause? For example, can I migrate my web application that I wrote on Windows without a change?

I am thinking of switching to Mac as Xamarin iOS development is much easier on Mac due to the restrictions imposed by iOS development. But I also write web API's and MVC pages and I wonder if there will be any problems in that aspect.

One other thing that occurred to me is that, will extensions like ReSharper be  available in VS for Mac too?

Comment: VS for Mac is a rebranded Xamarin Studio with some extra goodies from VS like the editor component which was ported over as far as I know, so you shouldn't expect much more then that. There is no .NET Framework for Mac, so you can't create any .NET Framework applications there, just .NET Core (which is one of the targets of ASP.NET Core)

Comment: As Xamarin Live Player is announced, you really should try to use that. Then you can always work on Windows and VS.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in one of the comments you're not able to use the full .NET Framework on Mac so you have some limitations as to the projects you can actually work on.

The mobile templates in VS4Mac do not include UWP so if you're doing `File -> New` you won't be able to work on UWP. If you are bringing over a project that includes projects like UWP that aren't exactly supported on Mac you should still be able to work on the code, you just cannot build or deploy.

There is some truth to VS4Mac being a rebranded Xamarin Studio. However, the changes they've introduced over the last year do back up what Miguel said at Build that they took actual bits from VS and replaced the XS components with the actual VS bits like the Debugger. You have to remember that VS4Mac is a Native Mac application and is meant to give you the feeling of working on Mac not PC (as it should).

Whether or not VS4Mac is for you is a question that only you can answer. That answer will vary from developer to developer, and frankly from task to task.

It's worth remembering though that VS4Mac is a v1 as far as an integration with the VS code base. I say that to remind you that not all of the features that we all want are going to be there right now.

As for support for tools like ReSharper, Microsoft cannot be realistically expected to determine what tools are going to be supported. That really is in the hands of JetBrains and when they decide to get the tooling out to the community.

As for the Xamarin Live Player... Remember it is a preview. Results are bound to vary from developer to developer. That said my testing to date has shown it's ok for very basic projects, but the second you put a framework behind it and use any sort of reflection it will not work at all and I'm not sure that will change.